# how to enable error log if i don't have access to php.ini

Tags: php

I have to mention that this question have been asked before and someone answered "You can still add configuration settings using a PHP file and not publish that into a public place (folder)." but i'm not quite sure what is that means so I'm asking if i don't have access to php.ini can i put this code in a php file and include it inside other files or there is a proper way for doing this

```
<?php
ini_set("error_reporting",E_ALL);
ini_set("log_error",1);
ini_set("error_log","error.log");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); //sets logging filter to log all errors
//error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); //sets logging filter to all except NOTICE, useful when your coding style is rather hacky (like mine)
ini_set('display_errors',1); //displays error output onpage
```

This should be sufficient.

Be warned that if an error occurs that generates output headers will be sent!
You cannot set cookies after this unless you use output buffering to catch possible errors and preventing the sending of headers on unwanted moments.

**Edit**

If you have or want to prevent problems caused by headers already been sent you can buffer the output and echo the output at the end of the page.

> Code with problem:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); //sets logging filter to log all errors
    ini_set('display_errors',1); //displays error output onpage
    if($a/*is not set*/){ //echoes to page: undefined variable in /path/index.php at line linenumber
        //code...
    }
    setcookie('testcookie','testvalue', time+3600); //error headers have already been sent so this won't work
```

> Code with fix

```
  <?php
    ob_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL); //sets logging filter to log all errors
    ini_set('display_errors',1); //displays error output onpage
    if($a/*is not set*/){ //echoes to buffer: undefined variable in /path/index.php at line linenumber
        //code...
    }
    setcookie('testcookie','testvalue', time+3600); //Works!
    //Rest of page
    echo ob_get_clean(); //this is the last line (add <?php if it's not already in a php tag)
```

Comment: this will affect anything below it, i would recommend it at the very top. But be warned about the headers being sent.

Comment: @ssd not at all, i ment at the top of the php page you are working in. If you would set this in php.ini it does not work differently than declared in each file

Comment: Just add these lines to the top of your code and you're basically good to go. If you want you can buffer the output to prepend it to your first intended output (answer edit incoming).