# Is there a way to paste display_errors code in another file than php.ini

Tags: .htaccess, file, php-ini

Hi I was trying to comment on this for advice

[Wordpress - The Jetpack server could not communicate with your site’s XML-RPC URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483162/wordpress-the-jetpack-server-could-not-communicate-with-your-site-s-xml-rpc-ur/56338647#56338647)

But It was suggested I ask a new question.
So here goes:

Is there any way to paste the code you suggested in the .htaccess file?
Or in another php file?

Because I can't find the php.ini file anywhere, tried to look everywhere.
(Yes, I searched in SO and google and youtube for answers, and tried it all)

So is there any way to edit the error_reporting somewehere else?

This is what I want to do to help with the connection between jetpack and website as delboy1978uk suggests.

set error_reporting to -1, turn display_errors off, and set a custom error_log. Then in the terminal, type tail -f /path/to/error_log

Thanks in advance for any advice you could give.
Reshma

Comment: There are some things in the question that suggest that you need to understand how to tell different things apart... The ``php.ini`` file is a _configuration_ file. It exists, if you fail to find it something is wrong. You need to resolve that. It typically is located under `/etc/php.....`, you can also simply ask your software management about the contents (files) of an installed package, here the package `apache_mod_php...` or similar, again, use the search function in there.  An `error_log` file is something you do _not_ edit, it is automatically written by the http server.

Comment: To answer your question: even if there were some other way to enable logging, what difference does that make? You should use the obvious and correct way. You operate an http server. You need to be able to control it. If you are not yet able to, then you need to find out things. There is no way around that!

Comment: Yeah I thought as much. I was hoping to maybe add error_reporting code to the .htaccess file as I did with xmlrpc.php. I'm currenty awaiting answer from my provider on where the php.ini file is.

Comment: If this is about a simple web hoster: in that case you certainly do _not_ have access to that `php.ini` file. Take a look at the documentation to see what other options you might have: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I just got answer from my hosting provider, they can't seem to locate the php.ini file either. Probably Simple web hoster as you pointed out. So according to the link I should create my own file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816310/how-to-enable-error-log-if-i-dont-have-access-to-php-ini?rq=1   I'm sorry to ask again. But is this what I can do? Put the code suggested in the link in another php file? Or in my case in the plugin.php file as it seems the error_reporting only needs to be edited in order to establish connection between Jetpack and my website. I much appreciate your help.

Comment: You do not need error logging to establish a connection. You need it to debug in case something does _not_ work as excepted. So it is a temporary measure. I would advise to directly insert the commands at the beginning of central files and remove them again once you have the information you need. However: I doubt you will be able to create an error log file in your personal file storage since you are using a web hoster. You will need to ask your provider for excerpts from the actual log file.

Comment: A general remark: it appears that you are trying to develop a solution directly on the hosted web space. That is a very bad idea. You definitely should develop locally, using a local development environment. That is only a few clicks in the software management anyway. Then, once you have a working solution, then is the time to deploy that o your hosted web space. The advantage is obvious: you have full control over your development environment which you lack for the hosted environment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the statement about something being a temporary measure got me thinking.
I already entered the following code to the www/.htaccess file to whitelist jetpack:

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order Allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from 192.0.78.24
Allow from 192.0.78.25
Satisfy all
</Files>
```

Now I copied it to the cms .htaccess file as well.
This solved the connection problem!

Of course now the slider on my website stopped working:(
So I deleted the code from the cms .htaccess file but left it in the www.htaccess file and I not only got my slider back up but the jetpack connection to my website did not get lost.
I tried to disconnect and connect again, and the connection was established again.
The jetpack debug page gives no errors anymore.

Still, there's nothing on the jetpacks dashboard page when I want to access it from my websites backend. I can only configure settings from the wordpress account.
But I will contact jetpack support for this.

Thank you for all your help.
Reshma

Answer (score 0):

**So I'm posting this answer also, because this was the last step in recovering the jetpack dashboard and settings page.**

I've tried to access my wp-admin via Chrome browser.
And that seemed to do the trick so to speak.
I was using Internet Explorer before.

But in Chrome, Jetpack works just fine!!

I have my dashboard and settings page back up in the websites back-end 
Yesss!!!
I have no explanation as to why jetpack suddenly wasn't working properly in IE anymore.
But I'm so happy that all is well now with my jetpack plugin.

I hope these two answers offer solutions for others who are experiencing the same issue.
(because it was a nightmare for me)

Kind regards, Reshma